# Working setup now broken : RevenueCat Flutter

Tags: revenuecat

I had an initial functioning setup to get offerings and make a purchase.  It worked : I could make a test purchase.

The code was in a ‘shop’ page, and I decided to move the RevenueCat initialisation to main.dart as initial entry point.  But maybe this wrong because it screwed everything up, and the app crashed on loading (error below).  So I put it back to what it was.

The app now loads and all screens function EXCEPT I am now getting the same error when I open the shop page.  Even though it was working before.

```
*** Assertion failure in +[RCPurchases sharedPurchases](), RCPurchases.m:160
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'There is no singleton instance. Make sure you configure Purchases before trying to get the default instance. More info here: https://errors.rev.cat/configuring-sdk'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x183586754 0x19804d7a8 0x1834883f8 0x1848afa6c 0x1009762f4 0x1009f2d34 0x100cb7bc0 0x100cb5b04 0x10109ea60 0x100dafd7c 0x1010b9070 0x1010531d4 0x1010559fc 0x18350122c 0x183500e28 0x183500278 0x1834fa02c 0x1834f9360 0x19ab37734 0x185f74584 0x185f79df4 0x100906e24 0x1831b5cf8)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00000001b169d334 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
->  0x1b169d334 <+8>:  b.lo   0x1b169d354               ; <+40>
    0x1b169d338 <+12>: pacibsp
    0x1b169d33c <+16>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1b169d340 <+20>: mov    x29, sp
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
Lost connection to device.
```

Error says I should configure Purchases …. but I did !

```
    static const revcatapiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    await Purchases.setDebugLogsEnabled(true);
    await Purchases.setup(revcatapiKey,
        appUserId: appUserId, observerMode: false);
```

I did `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`.  Same situation : app builds and loads and crashes on opening shop screen.

I don’t understand.  App is now in same state as it was before when working.

Any debug or reset suggestions?  Help!

Comment: The error is not that you're not configuring Purchases, but that you're accessing Purchases before calling `Purchases.setup`. I would double check your other calls to `Purchases.` to try to figure out which one is the one being executed before `Purchases.setup`

Comment: Thanks @Cesar, will check it out